# Insert chars into cstring

Tags: c

Trying to make function that converts `input_` buffer to its hex representation in `output_`. Got difficulties with simple operation - inserting string into string. I decided to move `output_` pointer to right after each sprintf by 2 possitions and at the end move pointer to starting position. But looks it might be dangerous, because according to my understanding I move position of array to another memory area that might be used for other purposes. Am I right? How to solve string insertion problem then?

```
void toHexS(const char* input_, char* output_ )
{


    int i=0;

     //for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    while(input_[i]!=0 )
     {
        stmcpy();
         sprintf(output_,"%02x", input_[i]);
         printf("%02x\n", input_[i]);
         output_++;
         output_++;

        i++;
     }

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j<i*2 ; j++)
    {
    output_--;
    }



}
```

Comment: What is the problem and what is the question? I assume you allocate memory outside from the scope of this function. That function has no way to know the allocated size. Do you have to reuse the result outside from the scope of this function? (I assume so). http://sscce.org/

Comment: Do you want to convert normal string in to hex string?

Comment: Yes, I need convert normal string in to hex string

Comment: why not instead of doing `output_++` just in `sprintf` do `sprintf(output_+i,...)` then you will get address of specific element of output array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure from your question what the problem is exactly.  Your code, while messy, should work.

You don't need the call to `stmcpy`, it doesn't do anything.

You don't need the for loop at the end.  The calling program has a pointer to output_, and C is normally pass by value, so it's OK.

Instead of doing `output_++` twice, use `output_ += 2;`.

A for loop would be a more natural fit here than a while loop.
`for (i=0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)`.